# Firebase bucket upload failing for one link but not the others via same API and filetype

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm having an issue with firebase bucket upload. My function gets links via an API to download them uploads them to storage. All the links in the API work except one and I'm not sure why that is, it's such an odd error and I can't pinpoint what the responseUrl is telling me. How come only one  failing but others aren't?

This is the error I'm getting from the bucket

```
[info] >  GaxiosError: Request failed with status code 400 {"user":"GaxiosError: Request failed with status code 400","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m GaxiosError: Request failed with status code 400"}}
[info] >      at Gaxios._request (/Users/bakrredwan/Desktop/Spring 2023/Junior Design/JID-2352-The-Emoroid-Digest-App-Backend/functions/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:129:23) {"user":"    at Gaxios._request (/Users/bakrredwan/Desktop/Spring 2023/Junior Design/JID-2352-The-Emoroid-Digest-App-Backend/functions/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:129:23)","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at Gaxios._request (/Users/bakrredwan/Desktop/Spring 2023/Junior Design/JID-2352-The-Emoroid-Digest-App-Backend/functions/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:129:23)"}}
[info] >      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>) {"user":"    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)"}}
[info] >      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {"user":"    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)"}}
[info] >      at async Upload.makeRequest (/Users/bakrredwan/Desktop/Spring 2023/Junior Design/JID-2352-The-Emoroid-Digest-App-Backend/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/gcs-resumable-upload.js:598:21) {"user":"    at async Upload.makeRequest (/Users/bakrredwan/Desktop/Spring 2023/Junior Design/JID-2352-The-Emoroid-Digest-App-Backend/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/gcs-resumable-upload.js:598:21)","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at async Upload.makeRequest (/Users/bakrredwan/Desktop/Spring 2023/Junior Design/JID-2352-The-Emoroid-Digest-App-Backend/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/gcs-resumable-upload.js:598:21)"}}
[info] >      at async Upload.getAndSetOffset (/Users/bakrredwan/Desktop/Spring 2023/Junior Design/JID-2352-The-Emoroid-Digest-App-Backend/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/gcs-resumable-upload.js:547:26) {"user":"    at async Upload.getAndSetOffset (/Users/bakrredwan/Desktop/Spring 2023/Junior Design/JID-2352-The-Emoroid-Digest-App-Backend/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/gcs-resumable-upload.js:547:26)","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at async Upload.getAndSetOffset (/Users/bakrredwan/Desktop/Spring 2023/Junior Design/JID-2352-The-Emoroid-Digest-App-Backend/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/gcs-resumable-upload.js:547:26)"}}
[info] >      at async Upload.continueUploading (/Users/bakrredwan/Desktop/Spring 2023/Junior Design/JID-2352-The-Emoroid-Digest-App-Backend/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/gcs-resumable-upload.js:341:9) { {"user":"    at async Upload.continueUploading (/Users/bakrredwan/Desktop/Spring 2023/Junior Design/JID-2352-The-Emoroid-Digest-App-Backend/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/gcs-resumable-upload.js:341:9) {","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     at async Upload.continueUploading (/Users/bakrredwan/Desktop/Spring 2023/Junior Design/JID-2352-The-Emoroid-Digest-App-Backend/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/gcs-resumable-upload.js:341:9) {"}}
[info] >    response: { {"user":"  response: {","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m   response: {"}}
[info] >      config: { {"user":"    config: {","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     config: {"}}
[info] >        method: 'PUT', {"user":"      method: 'PUT',","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       method: 'PUT',"}}
[info] >        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:9199/upload/storage/v1/b/the-emoroid-digest-app-882e5.appspot.com/o?name=PodcastMedia%2FDr_Boike_Podcast_Episode_Mix_-_7_21_22_551_PM6fpry.mp3&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=ccd96604-28fb-4131-bd36-9fa7b77c0a16', {"user":"      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:9199/upload/storage/v1/b/the-emoroid-digest-app-882e5.appspot.com/o?name=PodcastMedia%2FDr_Boike_Podcast_Episode_Mix_-_7_21_22_551_PM6fpry.mp3&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=ccd96604-28fb-4131-bd36-9fa7b77c0a16',","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       url: 'http://127.0.0.1:9199/upload/storage/v1/b/the-emoroid-digest-app-882e5.appspot.com/o?name=PodcastMedia%2FDr_Boike_Podcast_Episode_Mix_-_7_21_22_551_PM6fpry.mp3&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=ccd96604-28fb-4131-bd36-9fa7b77c0a16',"}}
[info] >        headers: [Object], {"user":"      headers: [Object],","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       headers: [Object],"}}
[info] >        validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)], {"user":"      validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)],","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)],"}}
[info] >        paramsSerializer: [Function: paramsSerializer], {"user":"      paramsSerializer: [Function: paramsSerializer],","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       paramsSerializer: [Function: paramsSerializer],"}}
[info] >        responseType: 'json' {"user":"      responseType: 'json'","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       responseType: 'json'"}}
[info] >      }, {"user":"    },","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     },"}}
[info] >      data: 'Bad Request', {"user":"    data: 'Bad Request',","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     data: 'Bad Request',"}}
[info] >      headers: { {"user":"    headers: {","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     headers: {"}}
[info] >        'access-control-expose-headers': 'content-type,x-firebase-storage-version,x-goog-upload-url,x-goog-upload-status,x-goog-upload-command,x-gupload-uploadid,x-goog-upload-header-content-length,x-goog-upload-header-content-type,x-goog-upload-protocol,x-goog-upload-status,x-goog-upload-chunk-granularity,x-goog-upload-control-url', {"user":"      'access-control-expose-headers': 'content-type,x-firebase-storage-version,x-goog-upload-url,x-goog-upload-status,x-goog-upload-command,x-gupload-uploadid,x-goog-upload-header-content-length,x-goog-upload-header-content-type,x-goog-upload-protocol,x-goog-upload-status,x-goog-upload-chunk-granularity,x-goog-upload-control-url',","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       'access-control-expose-headers': 'content-type,x-firebase-storage-version,x-goog-upload-url,x-goog-upload-status,x-goog-upload-command,x-gupload-uploadid,x-goog-upload-header-content-length,x-goog-upload-header-content-type,x-goog-upload-protocol,x-goog-upload-status,x-goog-upload-chunk-granularity,x-goog-upload-control-url',"}}
[info] >        connection: 'close', {"user":"      connection: 'close',","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       connection: 'close',"}}
[info] >        'content-length': '11', {"user":"      'content-length': '11',","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       'content-length': '11',"}}
[info] >        'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8', {"user":"      'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',"}}
[info] >        date: 'Sat, 28 Jan 2023 21:01:04 GMT', {"user":"      date: 'Sat, 28 Jan 2023 21:01:04 GMT',","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       date: 'Sat, 28 Jan 2023 21:01:04 GMT',"}}
[info] >        etag: 'W/"b-EFiDB1U+dmqzx9Mo2UjcZ1SJPO8"', {"user":"      etag: 'W/\"b-EFiDB1U+dmqzx9Mo2UjcZ1SJPO8\"',","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       etag: 'W/\"b-EFiDB1U+dmqzx9Mo2UjcZ1SJPO8\"',"}}
[info] >        vary: 'Origin', {"user":"      vary: 'Origin',","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       vary: 'Origin',"}}
[info] >        'x-powered-by': 'Express' {"user":"      'x-powered-by': 'Express'","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       'x-powered-by': 'Express'"}}
[info] >      }, {"user":"    },","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     },"}}
[info] >      status: 400, {"user":"    status: 400,","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     status: 400,"}}
[info] >      statusText: 'Bad Request', {"user":"    statusText: 'Bad Request',","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     statusText: 'Bad Request',"}}
[info] >      request: { {"user":"    request: {","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     request: {"}}
[info] >        responseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:9199/upload/storage/v1/b/the-emoroid-digest-app-882e5.appspot.com/o?name=PodcastMedia%2FDr_Boike_Podcast_Episode_Mix_-_7_21_22_551_PM6fpry.mp3&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=ccd96604-28fb-4131-bd36-9fa7b77c0a16' {"user":"      responseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:9199/upload/storage/v1/b/the-emoroid-digest-app-882e5.appspot.com/o?name=PodcastMedia%2FDr_Boike_Podcast_Episode_Mix_-_7_21_22_551_PM6fpry.mp3&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=ccd96604-28fb-4131-bd36-9fa7b77c0a16'","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       responseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:9199/upload/storage/v1/b/the-emoroid-digest-app-882e5.appspot.com/o?name=PodcastMedia%2FDr_Boike_Podcast_Episode_Mix_-_7_21_22_551_PM6fpry.mp3&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=ccd96604-28fb-4131-bd36-9fa7b77c0a16'"}}
[info] >      } {"user":"    }","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     }"}}
[info] >    }, {"user":"  },","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m   },"}}
[info] >    config: { {"user":"  config: {","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m   config: {"}}
[info] >      method: 'PUT', {"user":"    method: 'PUT',","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     method: 'PUT',"}}
[info] >      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:9199/upload/storage/v1/b/the-emoroid-digest-app-882e5.appspot.com/o?name=PodcastMedia%2FDr_Boike_Podcast_Episode_Mix_-_7_21_22_551_PM6fpry.mp3&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=ccd96604-28fb-4131-bd36-9fa7b77c0a16', {"user":"    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:9199/upload/storage/v1/b/the-emoroid-digest-app-882e5.appspot.com/o?name=PodcastMedia%2FDr_Boike_Podcast_Episode_Mix_-_7_21_22_551_PM6fpry.mp3&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=ccd96604-28fb-4131-bd36-9fa7b77c0a16',","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     url: 'http://127.0.0.1:9199/upload/storage/v1/b/the-emoroid-digest-app-882e5.appspot.com/o?name=PodcastMedia%2FDr_Boike_Podcast_Episode_Mix_-_7_21_22_551_PM6fpry.mp3&uploadType=resumable&upload_id=ccd96604-28fb-4131-bd36-9fa7b77c0a16',"}}
[info] >      headers: { {"user":"    headers: {","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     headers: {"}}
[info] >        'Content-Length': 0, {"user":"      'Content-Length': 0,","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       'Content-Length': 0,"}}
[info] >        'Content-Range': 'bytes */*', {"user":"      'Content-Range': 'bytes */*',","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       'Content-Range': 'bytes */*',"}}
[info] >        'x-goog-api-client': 'gl-node/16.16.0 gccl/5.20.5 gccl-invocation-id/37c940e8-01c8-4cf9-8fc8-64a4436a46bd', {"user":"      'x-goog-api-client': 'gl-node/16.16.0 gccl/5.20.5 gccl-invocation-id/37c940e8-01c8-4cf9-8fc8-64a4436a46bd',","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       'x-goog-api-client': 'gl-node/16.16.0 gccl/5.20.5 gccl-invocation-id/37c940e8-01c8-4cf9-8fc8-64a4436a46bd',"}}
[info] >        Accept: 'application/json' {"user":"      Accept: 'application/json'","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m       Accept: 'application/json'"}}
[info] >      }, {"user":"    },","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     },"}}
[info] >      validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)], {"user":"    validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)],","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)],"}}
[info] >      paramsSerializer: [Function: paramsSerializer], {"user":"    paramsSerializer: [Function: paramsSerializer],","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     paramsSerializer: [Function: paramsSerializer],"}}
[info] >      responseType: 'json' {"user":"    responseType: 'json'","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m     responseType: 'json'"}}
[info] >    }, {"user":"  },","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m   },"}}
[info] >    code: '400' {"user":"  code: '400'","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m   code: '400'"}}
[info] >  } {"user":"}","metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"function":{"name":"us-central1-UploadPodcastToStorage"},"extension":{},"message":"\u001b[90m> \u001b[39m }"}}
```

the responseURL shows the following:

```
{"error":{"code":404,"message":"No such object: upload/storage/v1/b/the-emoroid-digest-app-882e5.appspot.com/o","errors":[{"message":"No such object: upload/storage/v1/b/the-emoroid-digest-app-882e5.appspot.com/o","domain":"global","reason":"notFound"}]}}
```

The code at this point simply looks like this. I've initialized the bucket and imported all the correct firebase functions. I'm waiting for the download to finish then proceeding to upload, so how come the upload can't find the directory? it works for every other download of the exact same type.

```
async function savePodcastFromExternalLinkToStorageHelper(sourceLink: string, saveToFolder: string, docRef: DocumentReference<admin.firestore.DocumentData>) {
  const snap = await docRef.get();
  if (snap.data().media_storage != undefined) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve("Podcast: (" + snap.data().title + ") uploaded or already exists!");
    })
  }
  const tempDir = `/tmp/${saveToFolder}`;
  await download(sourceLink, `${tempDir}/`);
  let filename = fs.readdirSync(`${tempDir}/`).filter((fileName) =>
    fileName.startsWith(sourceLink.substring(sourceLink.lastIndexOf("/") + 1))
  );
  const stroagePath = `${saveToFolder}/${filename[0]}`;
  if (filename.length > 0) {
    try {
      await bucket.upload(`${tempDir}/${filename[0]}`, { destination: stroagePath })
      fs.rmSync(`${tempDir}/${filename[0]}`);
      const podcast = {
        media_storage: stroagePath,
      };
      await docRef.update(podcast);
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(snap.data().title + " sucessfully uploaded!")
      })
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      fs.rmSync(`${tempDir}/${filename[0]}`, { force: true });
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject(snap.data().title + " failed to upload")
      })
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Don't know the file name of ${sourceLink}`);
  }
}
```

Only one specific link is failing, and the others which are essentially the same filetype and from the same API are not, what might be the issue here?

I tried awaiting the function when it was called but that halts the firebase cloud function call as there is a timeout and memory limit, I need this to be asynchronously called without await for the function if that makes sense. Overall the issue is very odd as the links do work and I can access them.

If you need more info please say so and I can simply edit the post to add it. Apologies if I didn't post enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've actually figured out a solution to this. Thankfully the filetype for all the downloads are the same, so actually stating the content type 'audio/mp3' succeeded. Not sure why one singular upload did not succeed but the others did. Maybe a future fix for multiple filetypes is to pass in the type to declare based on the tag pulled from the metadata, so it never fails.